# How can I help my one month old poop with out hurting her?

Tags: infant

My daughter was born January 1st, 2016. I breastfeed her on a daily basis and She was having really good wet and messy diapers everyday for almost 2 1/2 weeks after coming home from the hospital but now she has been going almost 2 1/2 weeks without a messy diaper. I have tried to help her once in a while with a baby rectal thermometer and her poop still seems soft when she pushes out the poop and thermometer. She has been too the doctors about it and they just keep telling me that its just a gas block up that shes fine and they are having me give her gas drops and telling me to cut out dairy products to see if it helps plus to stop helping her with the thermometer because of risks of hurting her. So if the poop seems soft why cant she push it out and what can i do to help her?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I'm reading here (maybe incorrectly) that she hasn't pooped at all for 2 1/2 weeks. That's 17-18 days, is that correct? Or does she just not poop without rectal stimulation (the thermometer)? I just find it hard to believe your doctors would say it was fine for a baby not to poop for 18 days (but that's what they said?) Two more questions: did she pass her meconium within 24 hours of birth, and, finally, is this your first baby? Sorry that I'm asking so many questions. I'm sure we can suggest a few things.

Comment: You mention breastfeeding and also dairy.  What all are you feeding her?

Comment: I read it as the mom was asked to cut out dairy. Can you edit to clarify?

Comment: Dairy, as in cows milk, is not so good for newborns.  There is a lot they cannot be fed.  I agree with anongoodnurse - no doctor in their right mind is going to say its okay to not poop for a week.  More information is needed.

Comment: @EngrStudent - Please note that I did not say *no doctor in their right mind is going to say its okay to not poop for a week.* Personally, a week is something to talk to your doctor about, but it's not the same as 2 1/2 weeks, which is alarming. ;)

Comment: With my daugther who had some troubles sometime to poop (but never so long), we gave her a drop of olivo oil, and it worked. Hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping by now you've been able to get some help. I was wondering if you had tried carol syrup? If you dip your finger in it then let her suck on your finger that's all she would need. It's a natural, non-harming way to help the bowels move along. This also works on adults :)

BTW this is information from my mother, who is a CNA and my husband, who is an RN. It worked for us so thought it might help to know about.

Best of luck

Comment: I appreciate the great answers you've been contributing on the site. However, because this is medical advice for an infant, it would be best if you could link to a reputable source. Degrees people hold are not really relevant to answers on any SE site (my son is a nurse, and I'm very proud of him, but I wouldn't use that as confirmation of medical advice I was posting.) Answers like this should have references so people can do further reading. Flag after adding a source and the post notice will be lifted. Thanks.

Comment: (Btw, do you mean [Karo syrup](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/infant-and-toddler-health/expert-answers/karo-syrup-for-constipation/faq-20057931) which used to be used for infant constipation? I could not find carol syrup.)

Comment: lol, yes, Karo syrup.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these problems are akin to trying to answer the question, "Why won't my car start?"  There are so many factors, from medical problems to diet to disposition to environmental problems.

We could often coax gas our of our babies by holding the undersides of their thighs and gently pushing their knees up to their chest.  They seemed to like this, and occasionally it would make them poop a little.